# getting an error while fetching page title from database using codeigniter php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Fetching page title from database getting error as

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Trying to get
>   property of non-object Filename: controllers/digital_marketing.php
>   Line Number: 20
>
> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Trying to get
>   property of non-object Filename: controllers/digital_marketing.php
>   Line Number: 21

I am having two tables like 
1.digital_marketing
2.pagetitle

In the first table i am inserting the data related to digital marketing along with digitalmarketing_name(The table will be in the following format)

```
digital_id  description   digitalmarketing_name
1           dfhbsdjbfd     digital_marketing
```

Second Table:(pagetitle)

```
pagetitle_id  page_title            title
1             digital_marketing     Digital Marketing
```

In this i am comparing page_title if both the page_titles match then i need to display title name but while comparing that getting an error which i have posted above.

If i am using underscore(_) in the page title it is getting that error if not it is working fine.

Controller:

```
class Digital_marketing extends CI_Controller {
function __construct()
{ 
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('index_model');
    $this->load->model('digitalmarketing_model');

}
public function index()
{

    $data['records2']=$this->digitalmarketing_model->get_digitalmarketing();
    $pageReult = $this->digitalmarketing_model->getpagetitle($this->uri->segment(1));
    $data['page_title']=$pageReult->title;
    $data['meta_tags']=$pageReult->meta_tags;

    $data['mainpage'] = "digital-marketing";
    $this->load->view('templates/template',$data);
}
```

Model:

```
function getpagetitle($id)
{

    $this->db->select('P.*,D.digitalmarketing_name');       
    $this->db->from('pagetitle AS P');      
    $this->db->join('digital_marketing AS D','D.digitalmarketing_name=P.page_title','INNER');
    $this->db->where(array('P.page_title'=>$id));       
    $q=$this->db->get();        
    //var_dump($this->db->last_query());
    //print_r($q->num_rows());
    if($q->num_rows()>0)
      {
    $output = $q->result();

   return $output[0];
        }
    else
    {
    return false;
    }
}
```

The pagetitle which i have inserted in digital_marketing table it is my controller name.

Comment: Have u loaded model ?

Comment: @Gaurav i have loaded model

Comment: Please post your full controller code.

Comment: @NikuNjRathod Uploaded full controller code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your modal function

> Controller.php

```
    public function index()
        {

            $data['records2']=$this->digitalmarketing_model->get_digitalmarketing();
#echo $this->uri->segment(1); exit;
            $pageReult = $this->digitalmarketing_model->getpagetitle($this->uri->segment(1));
            $data['page_title']=$pageReult->title;
            $data['meta_tags']=$pageReult->meta_tags;

            $data['mainpage'] = "digital-marketing";
            $this->load->view('templates/template',$data);
        }
```

> Modal : digitalmarketing_model.php

```
function getpagetitle($id) {
    $this->db->select('p.*,d.digitalmarketing_name');
    $this->db->from('digital_marketing AS d');
    $this->db->join('pagetitle as p', 'p.page_title = d.digitalmarketing_name', 'left');
    $this->db->where('p.page_title',$id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        $row = $query->row();
        return $row;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I hope this will helps you.

Comment: please post your segments `$last = $this->uri->total_segments();
$record_num = $this->uri->segment($last);`

Comment: Not getting you were i need to post this

Comment: Please add above code in your controller inside action.

Comment: I have added next to these line $data['meta_tags']=$pageReult->meta_tags;   getting same error

Comment: Please print this in your controller action `$this->uri->segment(1)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154969/discussion-between-user6728960-and-nikunj-rathod).